# How to take objects from JSON, and use them into my site then?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I wrote some code to use JSON by AJAX. And It's not working in that way I want it to - I've got some undefinend stuff on my site.

I tried this:

```
let productsList = document.querySelector('.product-list-container__list-line');

function getDataAssync() {
    let httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let template = '';

    httpReq.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maksymilianMroz/items-for-ajax/master/items.json');
    httpReq.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            let content = this.responseText;
            content = JSON.parse(content);
            let klucze = Object.keys(content)
            console.log(content);
            console.log(klucze);

            klucze.forEach(element => {
                template +=
                    `<div class="product-list-container__list-item">
                        <img src="${element.gallery}">
                        <h4>${element.name}</h4>
                    </div>`
            });
            if(template != '') {
                productsList.innerHTML = template;
            }
        }
    });
    httpReq.send();
}

productsList.addEventListener('click', getDataAssync);
```

but the output of my actions was one div (I want all objects from JSON), with src=undefinend (I wanted first img from gallery array from JSON) and with name=undefinend (I wanted name from object from JSON)

I expect to put all items from JSON (not a single one) into div on my site - with the name (from JSON) and first img from items array called gallery (from JSON too) as src to my img.

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the json you're trying to parse

```
{
    "ShopItems" : [
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "name" : "Item1",
            "description" : "ONE Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.",
            "price" : "303120$",
            "gallery" : [
                "https://github.com/maksymilianMroz/items-for-ajax/blob/master/img/1.jpg?raw=true", 
                "https://github.com/maksymilianMroz/items-for-ajax/blob/master/img/2.jpg?raw=true", 
                "https://github.com/maksymilianMroz/items-for-ajax/blob/master/img/3.jpg?raw=true"
            ]
        }]
```

}

The  `let klucze = Object.keys(content)` returns the keys in the json: ShopItems. So the elements are the keys in the json, not the gallery items

Change your code to

```
        klucze.forEach(e => {
          images= content[e]
          images.forEach(element=>{
            template +=
                `<div class="product-list-container__list-item">
                    <img src="${element.gallery}">
                    <h4>${element.name}</h4>
                </div>`
          });
       });
```

Comment: My bad. Use ${element.gallery[0]}

Answer (score 0):

`klucze` is an array of the **names** of the properties in the object, which will be strings. Strings don't have properties called `gallery` or `name`. The actual items are in `content` (following your URL, specifically `content.ShopItems`). The minimal change would be to change `klucze.forEach` to `content.ShopItems.forEach`:

```
content.ShopItems.forEach(element => {
    template +=
        `<div class="product-list-container__list-item">
            <img src="${element.gallery}">
            <h4>${element.name}</h4>
        </div>`
});
```

That said, though, you're probably better off with `map` and `join`:

```
template = content.ShopItems.map(element =>
    `<div class="product-list-container__list-item">
        <img src="${element.gallery}">
        <h4>${element.name}</h4>
    </div>`
).join();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating the wrong variable. Object.keys() will deliver an array with names of object keys.

```
let klucze = Object.keys(content)
```

You want to iterate:

```
content['shopItems']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point of doing `Object.keys(content)`. Also there is `ShopItems` key inside the object which is an array. so you need to iterate this array to get the result.

Further `gallery` is an array. So `${element.gallery}` will not give any result unless index is passed. In this demo I have passed the 0 index

```js
let productsList = document.querySelector('.product-list-container__list-line');

function getDataAssync() {
  let httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let template = '';

  httpReq.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maksymilianMroz/items-for-ajax/master/items.json');
  httpReq.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      let content = this.responseText;
      let klucze = JSON.parse(content);
      klucze.ShopItems.forEach(element => {
        template +=
          `<div class="product-list-container__list-item">
                            <img src="${element.gallery[0]}">
                            <h4>${element.name}</h4>
                        </div>`
      });
      if (template != '') {
        productsList.innerHTML = template;
      }
    }
  });
  httpReq.send();
}

productsList.addEventListener('click', getDataAssync);
```

```html
<div class='product-list-container__list-line'>Click Here</div>
```